# How to create custom top links in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to create custom top links.
I do not have idea of how to place block in page.xml and any other layout file.
I do not have idea of how Magento default top links work.
If I want to create custom top links what should I do?

Comment: @Chilion thnaks.I found solution

Comment: Please post your solution so future visitors can easily see how you did it :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in page.xml
it should be child block of header block.

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="customlinks" as="customlinks"/>
```

Add this code in customer.xml

```html
<default>
        <reference name="customlinks">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
    <label>Register</label>
    <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>
    <title>Register</title>
    <prepare/>
    <urlParams/>
    <position>10</position>
   </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

add this code in your header.phtml file

```html
<?php echo $this->getChildhtml('customlinks') ?>
```

it will display link 'Register'